# Проблема при установке Mac OS на PC

Tags: macos

У меня проблема при установке Mac OS 10.10. Запуск происходит нормально но при загрузки полосатый дисплей и перезагрузка. https://youtu.be/7nOdnRNEixU

```
Описание устройства Intel(R) HD Graphics
Строка адаптера Intel(R) HD Graphics
Строка BIOS Intel Video BIOS
Тип видеопроцессора Intel(R) HD Graphics (Core i5)
Тип DAC Внутренний
Дата драйвера   26.11.2012
Версия драйвера 8.15.10.2900
Поставщик драйвера  Intel Corporation
Объем видеоОЗУ  1764784 КБ

Установленные драйверы  
igdumd64    8.15.10.2900
igd10umd64  8.15.10.2900
igdumdx32   8.15.10.2900
igd10umd32  8.15.10.2900

Поле    Значение
Свойства графического процессора    
Видеоадаптер    Intel Auburndale/Arrandale Processor - Integrated Graphics Controller
Версия BIOS Build Number: 2009 PC 14.34  03/11/2010  22:34:32
Дата BIOS   11.03.2010
Кодовое название ГП Ironlake-M
PCI-устройство  8086-0046 / 17AA-3920  (Rev 02)
Технологический процесс 45 nm
Тип шины    Встроено
Частота ГП  500 МГц
Частота RAMDAC  350 МГц
Пиксельные конвейеры    4
TMU на конвейер 1
Объединённые шейдеры    12  (v4.0)
Аппаратная поддержка DirectX    DirectX v10
Версия WDDM WDDM 1.1

Архитектура 
Архитектура Intel Gen5
Кэш L1 инструкций   4 КБ
Unified Return Buffer   64 КБ

Теоретическая пиковая производительность    
Пиксельная скорость заполнения  2000 Мпкс/с @ 500 МГц
Тексельная скорость заполнения  [ TRIAL VERSION ]
FLOPS с двойной точностью   [ TRIAL VERSION ]

Загрузка    
Выделенная память   60 МБ
Динамическая память 52 МБ
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема била в Intel(R) HD Graphics

[Intel HD Graphics](http://www.insanelymac.com/forum/topic/286092-guide-1st-generation-intel-hd-graphics-qeci/)